# Refactoring a website, HTML form no longer works

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on a website that was previously written by someone who had very little experience with web design and, suffice to say, it shows. The page I'm working on is a form submission page with two sections in the page that both contain inputs for that form. My issue is that, after my attempts to clean in up, the submit button no longer functions. I have not found any error messages or the like to explain what is going wrong.

Here is the original code:

```
<form name='ndc_app_form' id='ndc_app_form' method="post" action="../DM/dm_process_ndc.php">

    <table name="ndc_app_table" id="ndc_app_table" width="500" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4" class="tbl_bg">

      <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
          <p>Project</p>
        </td>
        <td width="350" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
          <input name="project" id="project" type="text" class="input">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
          <p>CMDB Application ID<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="350" valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
           <input name="app_id" id="app_id" type="text" class="input" required>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="150" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
          <p>CMDB Application Name<span style="color: red;"&nspb>*</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="350" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
           <input name="app_name" id="app_name" type="text" class="input" required>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
          <p>Application Support DL<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span></p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
           <input name="app_supp_dl" id="app_supp_dl" type="text" class="input" required>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
          <p>ESD Application Description</p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
          <p>
           <textarea name="app_notes" id="app_notes"></textarea>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
</div>
</table>

<div class="div2">
  <h3>Desired System Specifications:</h3>
  <h5><i>Note:<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span> indicates a required entry</i></h5>
  <form id='ndc_sys_info' name='ndc_sys_info' method="post" action="../DM/dm_process_ndc.php" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <!--<form id='pri_sys_info' name='pri_sys_info' onsubmit="return sysa_form_validation()" method="post">-->

    <table name="ndc_sys_tbl" id="ndc_sys_tbl" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4" border="2" bgcolor="#efefef">
      <tr>
        <th id="id">
          <font size=1>Row ID
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Environment<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Server Type<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Operating System<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Server Size<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Additional Storage
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Quantity<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Elevated Access Goup and/or Service Account (Root/Admin)<span style="color: red;" &nspb>*</span>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>System Notes
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
          <font size=2>Data Center
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#ffa500'></th>
        <!-- <th bgcolor='#ffa500'></th> -->
      </tr>
      
      <!-- Example informational row 1-->

      <tr>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Example
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>PROD
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Application
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Windows 2016
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Medium 4core x 16GB RAM
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>D:\ 250GB, F:\ 300GB
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>4
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>No:Read:AP-app-Support<br>Yes:Admin:AP-App-ADM
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Some system notes
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>National DC West
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'></th>
      </tr>
      
      <!-- Example informational row 2-->

      <tr>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Example
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>UAT
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Oracle Database
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Oracle Linux 7
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>(VM) Large DB (8core x 32GB RAM)
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>/u01 300GB<br>ASM_DATA:/dev/oracleasm/disks/D0001-D0004 (4 * Equal Sized disks of 256GB each, Tier 0 - Flash) : Total: 1024GB
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>3
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Yes:root:RG-IT-Oracleadmins<br>Yes:oracle:RG-IT-Oracleadmins
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>Some system notes
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
          <font size=1>National DC East
        </th>
        <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ndc_sys_tbl" name="ndc_sys_tbl" id="ndc_sys_tbl" align="center">1</td>
        <td>
          <div align="center">
            <select name="env[]" id="env" required>
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="PROD">PROD</option>
              <option value="DR">DR</option>
              <option value="UAT">UAT</option>
              <option value="QA">QA</option>
              <option value="DEV">DEV</option>
              <option value="DEV">SIT</option>
              <option value="POC">POC</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>

<!--////////// Start Quarterly Updates here \\\\\\\\\\-->

<td>
          <select name="serv_type[]" id="serv_type" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Application">Application</option>
            <option value="Web">Web</option>
            <option value="SQL Database">SQL Database</option>
            <option value="Oracle Database">Oracle Database</option>
            <option value="Mongo Database">Mongo Database</option>
            <option value="Other Database">Other Database</option>
            <option value="Hadoop">Hadoop</option>
            <option value="Appliance">Appliance</option>
            <option value="Other">Other (See Notes)</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name="os[]" id="os" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Windows 2019">Windows 2019</option>
            <option value="Windows 2016">Windows 2016</option>
            <option value="Windows 2012 R2">Windows 2012 R2</option>
            <option value="RedHat Linux 7">RedHat Linux 7</option>
            <option value="RedHat Linux 6">RedHat Linux 6</option>
            <option value="Oracle Linux 7">Oracle Linux 7</option>
            <option value="OVA">OVA</option>
            <option value="Other">Other (See Notes)</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name="server_size[]" id="server_size" required>
            <!-- Virtual Application or Web System Specifications -->
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="X-Small (2core x 8GB RAM)">X-Small (2core x 8GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Small (4core x 16GB RAM)">Small (4core x 16GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Small (OVM) (4core x 32GB RAM)">Small (OVM) (4core x 32GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Medium (8core x 32GB RAM)">Medium (8core x 32GB RAM)</option>           
            <option value="Large (8core x 64GB RAM)">Large (8core x 64GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="X-Large (16core x 64GB RAM)">X-Large (16core x 64GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="2X-Large (16core x 128GB RAM)">2X-Large (16core x 128GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="4X-Large (32core x 256GB RAM)">4X-Large (32core x 256GB RAM)</option>
              <option value="Other (See Notes)">Other (See Notes)</option>      
              
            <!-- Physical System Specifications -->
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="(PHY) Small (20core x 192GB RAM)">(PHY) Small (20core x 192GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="(PHY) Medium (24core x 384GB RAM)">(PHY) Medium (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="(PHY) Large (24core x 1535GB RAM)">(PHY) Large (24core x 1536B RAM)</option>
            <option value="(PHY) Max (48core x 1535GB RAM)">(PHY) Max (48core x 1536B RAM)</option>
            <option value="Other (Approval Required)">Other (Approval Required)</option>

            <!-- Hadoop Viritul System Spcifications -->
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Hadoop Kafka (16core x 192GB RAM)">Hadoop Kafka (16core x 192GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Hadoop Hbase (32core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Hbase (32core x 384GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Hadoop Data (24core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Data (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Hadoop Master/Edge/Name (24core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Master/Edge/Name (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Hadoop NiFi 8core x 192GB RAM)">Hadoop Data (8core x 192GB RAM)</option>
            <option value="Hadoop Isilon Data (32core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Isilon Data (32core x 384GB RAM)</option>

            <!-- Other Non standard offering -->
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Other (See Notes)">Other (See Notes)</option>
          </select>
        </td>

<!--////////// End Update here \\\\\\\\\\-->

        <td><textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="add_storage" name="add_storage[]"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="qty[]" required></td>
        <td><textarea rows="7" cols="40" id="elevated_access" name="elevated_access[]" required></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea name="sys_notes[]"></textarea></td>
              
        <td align="center">
          <select name="dc[]" id="dc">
            <option value=" "></option>
            <option value="National DC East">National DC East</option>
            <option value="National DC West">National DC West</option>
            <option value="Coudersport">Coudersport</option>
            <option value="Greenville - Approval Required">Greenville - Approval Required</option>
            <!--
            <option value="Orlando - Approval Required">Orlando - Approval Required</option>
            <option value="Tampa - Approval Required">Tampa - Approval Required</option>
            -->
            <option value="Hawaii - Approval Required">Hawaii - Approval Required</option>
            <option value="Other(See Notes)">Other(See Notes)</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td><input type="button" style="background-color:#808080;color:white" ; value="Delete Row" onclick="ndc_sys_tbl_ob_adRows.delRow(this)" /></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Add Row and Submit buttons -->
<div class="btn-container">
  <input class="btn-Row" type="button" style="background-color:#0000ff;color:white" ; value="Add Row" onclick="ndc_sys_tbl_ob_adRows.addRow()" />
  <input class="btn-Sub" type="submit" id="btnSubItem" style="background-color:GREEN;color:white" ; value="Submit">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //JS class to add/delete rows in html table - https://coursesweb.net/javascript/
  //receives table id
  function adRowsTable(id) {
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
    var me = this;
    if (document.getElementById(id)) {
      var row3 = table.rows[3].outerHTML;

      //adds index-id in cols with class .tbl_id
      function setIds() {
        var ndc_sys_tbl = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' .ndc_sys_tbl');
        for (var i = 0; i < ndc_sys_tbl.length; i++) ndc_sys_tbl[i].innerHTML = i + 1;
      }

      //add row after clicked row; receives clicked button in row
      me.addRow = function(btn) {
        btn ? btn.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', row3) : table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row3);
        setIds();
      }

      //delete clicked row; receives clicked button in row
      me.delRow = function(btn) {
        btn.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
        setIds();
      }
    }
  }

  //create object of adRowsTable(), pass the table id
  var ndc_sys_tbl_ob_adRows = new adRowsTable('ndc_sys_tbl');
</script>

</form>
</div>
```

Let me address a few obvious issues with this so this section doesn't fill up with comments:

- Yes, this site was written in HTML4. It was indeed written in 2020
- Yes, those are inline styles
- Yes, that is a deprecated form tag
- Yes, the closing tags are a mess and yes, there is indeed one closing form tag and two opening form tags
- No, I have no idea how this site is functional, but it apparently is.

Anyways, I cleaned up the code and this is the version I'm trying to use:

```
<div>
    <h3>Application Information:</h3>
    <h5><i>Note:<span &nspb>*</span &nspb>indicates a required entry</i></h5>
    <form name='ndc_app_form' id='ndc_app_form' method="post" action="../DM/dm_process_ndc.php">
        <table name="ndc_app_table" id="ndc_app_table" class="tbl_bg">
            <tr>
                <td width="150" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <p>Project</p>
                </td>
                <td width="350" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <input name="project" id="project" type="text" class="input">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="150" valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
                    <p>CMDB Application ID<span &nspb>*</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="350" valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
                    <input name="app_id" id="app_id" type="text" class="input" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="150" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <p>CMDB Application Name<span &nspb>*</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="350" valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <input name="app_name" id="app_name" type="text" class="input" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
                    <p>Application Support DL<span &nspb>*</span></p>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="lft_bdr">
                    <input name="app_supp_dl" id="app_supp_dl" type="text" class="input" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <p>ESD Application Description</p>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="alt lft_bdr">
                    <textarea name="app_notes" id="app_notes"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <h3>Desired System Specifications:</h3>
    <h5><i>Note:<span &nspb>*</span> indicates a required entry</i></h5>
    <form id='ndc_sys_info' name='ndc_sys_info' method="post" action="../DM/dm_process_ndc.php" onSubmit="return validate()">
        <table name="ndc_sys_tbl" id="ndc_sys_tbl" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4" border="2" bgcolor="#efefef">
            <tr>
                <th id="id">
                    <font size=1>Row ID
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Environment<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Server Type<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Operating System<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Server Size<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Additional Storage
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Quantity<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Elevated Access Goup and/or Service Account (Root/Admin)<span &nspb>*</span>
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>System Notes
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'>
                    <font size=2>Data Center
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#ffa500'></th>
                <!-- <th bgcolor='#ffa500'></th> -->
            </tr>
            <!-- Example informational row 1-->
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Example
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>PROD
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Application
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Windows 2016
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Medium 4core x 16GB RAM
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>D:\ 250GB, F:\ 300GB
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>4
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>No:Read:AP-app-Support<br>Yes:Admin:AP-App-ADM
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Some system notes
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>National DC West
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'></th>
            </tr> 
            <!-- Example informational row 2-->
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Example
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>UAT
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Oracle Database
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Oracle Linux 7
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>(VM) Large DB (8core x 32GB RAM)
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>/u01 300GB<br>ASM_DATA:/dev/oracleasm/disks/D0001-D0004 (4 * Equal Sized disks of 256GB each, Tier 0 - Flash) : Total: 1024GB
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>3
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Yes:root:RG-IT-Oracleadmins<br>Yes:oracle:RG-IT-Oracleadmins
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>Some system notes
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'>
                    <font size=1>National DC East
                </th>
                <th bgcolor='#b3e6b3'></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ndc_sys_tbl" name="ndc_sys_tbl" id="ndc_sys_tbl" align="center">1</td>
                <td>
                    <div align="center">
                        <select name="env[]" id="env" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="PROD">PROD</option>
                            <option value="DR">DR</option>
                            <option value="UAT">UAT</option>
                            <option value="QA">QA</option>
                            <option value="DEV">DEV</option>
                            <option value="DEV">SIT</option>
                            <option value="POC">POC</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <!--////////// Start Quarterly Updates here \\\\\\\\\\-->
                <td>
                    <select name="serv_type[]" id="serv_type" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Application">Application</option>
                        <option value="Web">Web</option>
                        <option value="SQL Database">SQL Database</option>
                        <option value="Oracle Database">Oracle Database</option>
                        <option value="Mongo Database">Mongo Database</option>
                        <option value="Other Database">Other Database</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop">Hadoop</option>
                        <option value="Appliance">Appliance</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other (See Notes)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="os[]" id="os" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Windows 2019">Windows 2019</option>
                        <option value="Windows 2016">Windows 2016</option>
                        <option value="Windows 2012 R2">Windows 2012 R2</option>
                        <option value="RedHat Linux 7">RedHat Linux 7</option>
                        <option value="RedHat Linux 6">RedHat Linux 6</option>
                        <option value="Oracle Linux 7">Oracle Linux 7</option>
                        <option value="OVA">OVA</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other (See Notes)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="server_size[]" id="server_size" required>
                    <!-- Virtual Application or Web System Specifications -->
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="X-Small (2core x 8GB RAM)">X-Small (2core x 8GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Small (4core x 16GB RAM)">Small (4core x 16GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Small (OVM) (4core x 32GB RAM)">Small (OVM) (4core x 32GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Medium (8core x 32GB RAM)">Medium (8core x 32GB RAM)</option>           
                        <option value="Large (8core x 64GB RAM)">Large (8core x 64GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="X-Large (16core x 64GB RAM)">X-Large (16core x 64GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="2X-Large (16core x 128GB RAM)">2X-Large (16core x 128GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="4X-Large (32core x 256GB RAM)">4X-Large (32core x 256GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Other (See Notes)">Other (See Notes)</option>          
                        <!-- Physical System Specifications -->
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="(PHY) Small (20core x 192GB RAM)">(PHY) Small (20core x 192GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="(PHY) Medium (24core x 384GB RAM)">(PHY) Medium (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="(PHY) Large (24core x 1535GB RAM)">(PHY) Large (24core x 1536B RAM)</option>
                        <option value="(PHY) Max (48core x 1535GB RAM)">(PHY) Max (48core x 1536B RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Other (Approval Required)">Other (Approval Required)</option>
                        <!-- Hadoop Viritul System Spcifications -->
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Hadoop Kafka (16core x 192GB RAM)">Hadoop Kafka (16core x 192GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop Hbase (32core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Hbase (32core x 384GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop Data (24core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Data (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop Master/Edge/Name (24core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Master/Edge/Name (24core x 384GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop NiFi 8core x 192GB RAM)">Hadoop Data (8core x 192GB RAM)</option>
                        <option value="Hadoop Isilon Data (32core x 384GB RAM)">Hadoop Isilon Data (32core x 384GB RAM)</option>
                        <!-- Other Non standard offering -->
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Other (See Notes)">Other (See Notes)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <!--////////// End Update here \\\\\\\\\\-->
                <td><textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="add_storage" name="add_storage[]"></textarea></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="5" name="qty[]" required></td>
                <td><textarea rows="7" cols="40" id="elevated_access" name="elevated_access[]" required></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea name="sys_notes[]"></textarea></td>  
                <td align="center">
                    <select name="dc[]" id="dc">
                        <option value=" "></option>
                        <option value="National DC East">National DC East</option>
                        <option value="National DC West">National DC West</option>
                        <option value="Coudersport">Coudersport</option>
                        <option value="Greenville - Approval Required">Greenville - Approval Required</option>
                        <!--
                        <option value="Orlando - Approval Required">Orlando - Approval Required</option>
                        <option value="Tampa - Approval Required">Tampa - Approval Required</option>
                        -->
                        <option value="Hawaii - Approval Required">Hawaii - Approval Required</option>
                        <option value="Other(See Notes)">Other(See Notes)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input id="btnDelRow" type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="ndc_sys_tbl_ob_adRows.delRow(this)" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Add Row and Submit buttons -->
<div class="btn-container">
    <input id="btnAddRow" class="btn-Row" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="ndc_sys_tbl_ob_adRows.addRow()" />
    <input class="btn-Sub" type="submit" id="btnSubItem" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Notable changes are that I removed some of the inline css (not all yet, it has literally been giving me headaches) and added closing tags for both form tags. I aso moved that javascript part to the bottom of the page, so it is still in the file even though this code segment doesn't include it. Unfortunately, while the code at least looks cleaner now, the submit button no longer works.

With this in mind, what would be the best way to refactor my version of the code so that the submit button submits all the information from both form tags? I've tried changing the second form tag to a div, moving the onSubmit attribute to the first form tag, and effectively wrapping the whole thing with only the first form tag, but that didn't work.

Edit: Some more specific info about the current state of the page: When the submit button is clicked, it is supposed to use a program to submit the form info and redirect to a success page. Currently, when the submit button is clicked, nothing happens and the page remains unchanged as if the button was never clicked. There are no errors or messages in the console or anything of the like, and it doesn't appear that the info is being submitted.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does the page just sit there and not submit (dm_process_ndc.php doesn't get called)? Does it submit and not process anything (dm_process_ndc.php not doing what it's supposed to)? Do you get errors in the console? And on a side note, in your version I see `<span &nspb>` which doesn't make sense, and you're using obsolete tags like `<font>`

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, this site was originally designed by someone who doesn't know anything about web development and he was using obsolete font tags. I haven't gotten around to removing those yet, but the page is still using HTML 4 and the original code does function. I'm planning on fixing these issues at some point, but my priority is cleaning this up and making it functional again for now.

Comment: You didn't answer my others questions. Especially the console one

Comment: As for the rest, normally when the submit button is pressed, a php program is used to submit the form info and the page redirects to a success page. Currently, when the button is pressed, nothing happens and the page remains unchanged. As I mentioned above, there are no errors in the console or anything of the like. It just doesn't seem to function and it doesn't look like the info is getting submitted to the database.

Comment: Some tags are not supported in HTML 5, so try use HTML 5 instead.

Comment: _"As I mentioned above, there are no errors in the console"_ Where was this exactly?

Comment: @TobyHarnish I do plan to update to HTML5, but this application is currently in production (*sigh* I know) and my client wants make some functional changes first before I can fully overhaul this thing.

Comment: @j08691 I thought I had included that information but it appears I was mistaken. My bad. I'll add an edit to include that info.

Comment: I think the problem is you closed the form tag - you should have just removed the second opening form tag and moved the validation onto the first for tag

Comment: @Pete I've tried removing the second opening tag and converting it to a div, so that there is only the first opening form tag and a single close tag around the whole section. That didn't appear to work.

Comment: You'll need to post the JavaScript for this code as well. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't know where the page should sent to since you put the

```
<input>
```

tag outside of the

```
<form>
```

tag. Put the submit button inside the last

```
<form>
```

and it should work.

Comment: This was the solution. It looks like, in the early code, a closing form tag was included way down and the submit button was thus enclosed. I changed the second form tag to a div and wrapped all of it in the first form tag, but this time I moved the section containing the submit button inside that form tag. When I clicked the submit button, everything worked as it should. 

Thanks!